# A new puzzling approach

Tags: riddle, word

> Sometimes I am very small
>   But sometimes even tall
>   My name is sometimes spoken with a humans fighter name
>   but I am not a human at all
>   you can throw me but not If I am too heavy
>   And even if I'm very light I cannot walk away
>   Once I was a part of a union
>   But now I am a one-man-Army seeking for a revolution
>   I was cut and separated from my Family
>   But you can pick your family and climb on me

I hope this not too heavy for you ;)

EDIT: I think now it's a little bit easier and more precise ;)

Comment: I am sure these clues all perfectly fit what you're thinking, but they fit many other things as well. For example, a ball can be thrown unless it's too heavy, it can't walk, and it's a last name so John Ball would meet the name clue. The same is true of rock, stick, and many other inanimate objects that come in different sizes. You need some sort of confirmer clue that would ONLY apply to the correct answer.

Comment: okay, wait a moment.

Comment: okay. Have done it a lot easier. The third line is the most important :D

Comment: That basically gives it away now.. You could figure it out with the first 4 lines

Comment: yeah it does. But the complain from all the guys here led me to this...

Comment: @Snickbrack I think there are many better ways to clue a rock. :) Anyway, its solved. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the edit to the puzzle, I'm thinking

> Rock

Sometimes I am very small
But sometimes even tall

> Rocks come in all shapes and sizes

My name is sometimes spoken with a humans fighter name
but I am not a human at all

> Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson. He's also an actor, which is what the clue was originally.

you can throw me but not If I am too heavy
And even if I'm very light I cannot walk away

> You can throw rocks, and rocks can't move by themselves

Once I was a part of a union

> Rocks were once part of bigger rocks.

But now I am a one-man-Army seeking for a revolution

> Violent protestors (i.e. during revolutions) will throw rocks

I was cut and separated from my Family

> Like I said, rocks were once part of bigger rocks

But you can pick your family and climb on me

> Rock-climbing

Comment: "easy" as it is ;)

Answer (score 6):

This could be a little broad but I would go for a try and say...

Are you

> **A Tree**

Sometimes I am very small
But sometimes even tall

> Some trees are small while some are tall.

My name is sometimes spoken with a humans name
but I am not a human at all

> Surnames which are spoken with human's name form a family tree. Also, *Woods* which can be connected with Humans name. Also, there are people with Surname as *Tree* e.g. [David Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Tree)

you can throw me but not If I am too heavy
And even if I'm very light I cannot walk away

> You can throw a tree by lifting it if its not heavy. Also, a tree can't walk.

Once I was a part of a union
But now I am a one-man-Army seeking for a revolution

> Union is referring to forest or a group of trees. But, due to industrialization, the forests are reducing and hence the number of trees as well. Green revolution is for saving the trees.

I was cut and separated from my Family

> A tree separated from forest.

But you can pick your family and climb on me

> Family tree probably.

Comment: This is what I thought of.. I think he could have done without the last two lines, saying cut and referring to families again makes it seem super obvious, but the union/revolution bit helps make it specific.

Comment: Got there just before me. Also: "Ash" and "Olive" are given names as well as species of tree.

Comment: This could also be an answer to my riddle but it isn't. Have commented on my post.

Comment: @Snickbrack I can easily find an actor name containing word **Tree** :)

Comment: okay, now it should be clear...